# Running Multiple servers on CentOS 5

Tags: centos5, httpd

I have to run httpd on 3 ports of my centos installation.I chose port 80,8080 and 8081.I can access all three ports from the server machine,but not from the other machines in the network.When i tried nmap from the server terminal i got the following output.

```
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
25/tcp   open  smtp
80/tcp   open  http
111/tcp  open  rpcbind
443/tcp  open  https
631/tcp  open  ipp
936/tcp  open  unknown
3306/tcp open  mysql
8080/tcp open  http-proxy
8081/tcp open  blackice-icecap
```

I can access the port 80 application from the whole network.Whats blocking the ports 8080 and 8081?

Comment: Before you suspect that something is blocking port 8080 and 8081, you should verify that your httpd is actually listening on those ports. Please run `netstat -n -l -t` on the server and include its output in the question.

Comment: httpd is listening at these ports,as I can access my sites as 127.0.0.1:8080 etc

Answer (score 1):

Your firewall is doing it's job.